# Buck Converter Simulation in OrCAD Capture Lite

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, buck, powermosfet, orcad

I have this really simple buck converter circuit but I am getting really funny results.

[image: Buck Converter Schematic]

[image: Simulation results]

I tried different input voltages (12-650 V), no matter what I put, it doesn't affect the output. The output voltage amplitude changes with the change in PWM voltage amplitude. Changing the duty cycle doesn't change the Vout amplitude either. I tried different MOSFETS as well which also included SiCs, IGBTs, etc.

Been stuck at this for a few days now, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Some edits after all the helpful comments. I am using the Boostrap circuit as @hacktastical suggested. This is my circuit now.
[image]

The only problem is I am getting 0.6V ripple, are there any tips on dropping it down to 0.1V?
[image]

Comment: You can't use a N channel FET as a high side switch like that. You need a P channel FET or some bootstrapping system for the N channel.

Comment: Your question is also  missing all the important details of components and the design specs.

Comment: @Unimportant, we can use both for a Buck converter. Textbooks might show P channel cuz it is simpler, manufacturers use N channel because it is cheaper.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I believe I have all the important specs on my schematic. And the design specs are well, I just wanna learn. Let me know if there is anything specific that you wanted.

Comment: If you read and understand any Power convert simulation tool you will learn the importance of ESR for caps , DCR for coils, Ron for FETs and diodes, and ultimately Q from the series reactance ratio for damping the resonance or instability during a step load start or change. This affects the startup power to load power ratio greatly and overshoot on voltage.

Comment: @Saagar No, you have a source follower now.

Comment: V1 must be > Vout + 2.5 Vt but not exceed 15v + Vt in a follower.  This won’t work. [Edited by a moderator]

Comment: All - Please keep things civil and remember the [Code of Conduct](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/conduct). *Polite* technical disagreement is allowed. However, don't post anything that could *feel* personal, even when applied to content and not the person. One or more comments have been deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an n-FET on the high side, you will need to bring the gate voltage *above* the switch node voltage to turn the FET on. Bear in mind, the switch node normally swings between GND and Vin, so you have to have at least Vin + Vgs threshold at the gate to get the job done.

The typical way to do that is to use a *boostrap* circuit to develop this higher-than-max voltage. Below is a DCDC that uses a bootstrap ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjOB0AMt-CwFMC0B2E1IDY0E4AOAJgFY98BmI6CggiCikE56Z1MMAKACVm1sIFGAAsIkNmgEhYSZnki2YIvLZYSXAO4gR2caPG79RadC4BjCXXB4V2awdUxYRagnewmKEpGV4RdFQiRBSiBCxYsNwANhJE%20mJW0o4qkfCuUOGyRGAUaBR4LnihmFpJIERoKkYVVaUA5iBoJCqVKs2t1mplHeCJ9smJZtq9beVjZgDyTS194gSwc%20Cl2jVjimwTZTVUOnogCyt74vFsa3XDxwdn%203iClzWOInfgAqWWz4LK0p8S4krODzuZDoGQUXxiCgiEi4ES0bB4EimZzcVYBP46F77MwAE0xX0Ev32KhxSAAZgBDACu0QALtt9rJ8eB7gz9IT9rszAAnHSLfYbcDKeRgODbXacaqLSVHMTSAX8-5cMk6CXCx7CiWQFhgDQqij2cAmPlKY1aiIwIhlA3JM2zb6lXkDWp2By2JywNDbF5PH3Gh4%20t5rKSO-hffrxJZqZxe1Y%20xIkN6OMyNQVPaVybqWFrSFAvROCPP3TCAkRoIHufRgSB4fwUaDYSRSWjNe4oriNMgqIvMd0oQ7dbQkYXCRI1UdK3k5mQJt4Tj3QDRDuf5vsvS7TnvD7vrsrboT5kfJvfG%20f7%20cPfbzx6s3mjOq9ZMVGtVb3hwyB1kANwqiiN0nrYxTAqE04GfFgiG1Jw4W2RYxlOF0jgQ%20C-wdXErgQ4NpBUMAADlE04LgAEkQEA-9SPtf0SxYDQAHsKiUBRODOaN4HIbAYVIeRWjYCguHo5IFGgQhwGjCBxK4Wg%20ScHiQB4JAAGcAEsFNpCkADtzCQSTgLYCC2AANVoukKXqbSpOCZgRUWAARKlaQATwAHQUgBhBzzGibSgA))

[image]

The scope trace on the left is the gate drive for the n-FET. You'll notice that it swings between 0 and 2x Vin (24V in case). This ensures the FET turns on fully with minimum drain-source resistance.

Comment: thanks a  lot, @hacktastical, I used bootstrap circuit as you suggested. I will try adding the circuit in the question. I can now convert the 400 V to 8V, the only thing is my ripple is 5V, I might be using the wrong equations. Are there different equations to calculate the inductor and capacitor values for HV?

Comment: The challenge with such a high stepping ratio is the minimum on time for the high side switch will be very short. Suggest using 2 or 3 stages to step it down.

Comment: That said, a step down from 600V would be better accomplished using a flyback (transformer) based topology.

Comment: You also need to consider limiting the max Vgs to a safe value.

Answer (score 0):

You have M1 wired as a source follower: -

[image]

This means that the voltage on the source is largely unaffected by the input voltage on the drain and this is what you see. Try using a P channel MOSFET instead or use a gate-source drive voltage that can operate M1 as a proper switching transistor.

Comment: "Try using a P channel MOSFET instead or use a gate-source drive voltage that can operate M1 as a proper switching transistor" The P-FET would also need a "gate-source drive".

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to drive a MOSFET that is switching 600V, I recommend using an isolated gate drive. You could use a bootstrap driver like @hacktastical suggested, but it probably makes more sense to use an isolated gate drive instead, something like this:

[image]

I have [simulated this circuit](https://everycircuit.com/circuit/6347832565694464) on everycircuit. You can take a look at it.

[image]

And here is an application of the isolated gate drive circuit in a [half-bridge inverter](https://everycircuit.com/circuit/4631917230817280/200w-square-wave-inverter):

[image]

Comment: thank you @Prathik Prashanth, I will definitely try that.